# Encode Base64 in JavaScript, send with GET, decode in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, get, base64

I thought this will be an easy Google-search, but it seems that my technique is not as common as I thought.

How can I `encode` a `Base64` string in JavaScript, in order to put it safely on the line with a `GET` parameter (my `Base64` string contains a lot of `/`, `+` and `=`, and `decode` the exact same string in PHP, in order to store it in a database?

When I post the Base64 string without encoding, my PHP script does not accept it.

I [found a solution](https://jsfiddle.net/magikMaker/7bjaT/) for encoding and decoding the `Base64` string in JavaScript, but not in the way it makes sense for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "`encode` a `Base64` string"? Convert a string to `base64` representation? Can you include `javascript`, `php` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: No, I mean, how can I make it "URL-safe", because it contains some `/` and `+` and `=`

Comment: @JohnBrunner See my answer, let me know if you need a more fleshed out example.

Comment: Why can you not use `POST` request? How is `base64` string generated?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So in javascript (*updated with encoding URI*):

```
var myStr = "I am the string to encode";
var token = encodeURIComponent(window.btoa(myStr));
```

[btoa example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa)

You should be then able to add that base64 encoded string to your get request.

Then in PHP, after you retrieve the request:

```
<?php
   $str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
   echo base64_decode(urldecode($str));
?>
```

[base64_decode docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Comment: `nodejs` does not appear at tags at Question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I asked the question wrong. I already got a Base64 string, and I want to send it via GET to my server. Problem is, that the Base64 string contains a lot of / and +, which is not safe for GET. How can I send it safely via GET?

Comment: @JohnBrunner To send it safely via a GET request you have to urlencode it client side. See my updated answer (javascript) for how todo that. Cheers.

Comment: @JohnBrunner Was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: To be clear it should be reversed in php: 
`echo base64_decode(urldecode($str));`

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript

```
var password ="xyz"
window.btoa(password)
```

In php

```
$password = urldecode(base64_decode($_POST['password']));
```