# javascript image base64 and php image base64_encode are different

Tags: javascript, php, base64

I have an jpeg image and I am trying to get the base64 encoded string with both javascript & php.

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

var base64 = getBase64Image(document.getElementById('myImg'));
console.log(base64)
```

Here is the [javascript fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oy4vj2wm/1/).

---

Now, with the same image with php code

```
$url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff/lossy-page1-256px-SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg" 

var_dump(base64_encode(file_get_contents($url));
```

---

```
// The Javascript result:
"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh......LGoT8H4JpIaDthj+xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"

// The PHP result:
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA......nbKBwJCElGEDnboCdvdE5pDlGThLlNC/9k="
```

---

I made the [changes in Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/oy4vj2wm/2/) that @JaromandaX suggested, now the Javascript string's beginning looks similar but not the end.

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");
```

New Javascript Output:
    "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA......A4EhCSjCBzt0BO3uic0hyjccJcpoX//2Q=="

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode Base64 in JavaScript, send with GET, decode in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165891/encode-base64-in-javascript-send-with-get-decode-in-php)

Comment: you have a PNG in javascript and a JPEG in php - so, of course they'll be different

Comment: try `"image/jpeg"` for the type if you want jpeg - you'll also need `/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/`

Comment: @JaromandaX I made the change you suggested (check OP), but the ending is still not identical.

Comment: @Raymond How is this duplicate of encoding in js and decoding in php? I am not even making a request from js to php - trying to figure out with pure js and pure php - completely standalone

Comment: Can you check the length of both outputs? It's possible that the php one contains the file metadata

Comment: One is the direct file from the source (PHP) ... the other is a canvas - so, some "processing" has been done most likely

Comment: @ Ibu they are different - js: 14456, php: 14440  @JaromandaX hmm, makes sense.  But then how can I get the encoded base64 image from javascript that match the one with php? Is there any way?

Comment: yes, read the image file directly like you do in PHP - don't need a canvas

Comment: The canvas "processing" seems to be true. Posting an answer now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is, you're reading a jpeg into the canvas, then producing the jpeg from the canvas ... so there's some processing going on (jpeg quality setting for example would be different)

To get identical results in javascript, simply don't use a canvas - fetch the image, and using Blob + FileReader, extract the base64

```js
fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff/lossy-page1-256px-SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg').then(r => r.blob()).then(blob => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var b64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');
        console.log(`${b64.slice(0,20)}...${b64.slice(-20)}`);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
});
```

Comment: Your solution is even better! Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this also work with SVGs? I mean SVG to PNG conversion?

Answer (score 1):

As @JaromandaX suggested in the comments,

> *"One is the direct file from the source (PHP) ... the other is a canvas - so, some "processing" has been done most likely"*

Using this chunk gives the exact same base64 string:

```
var url = document.getElementById('myImg').getAttribute('src')
var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHTTP.open('GET', url, true);
xmlHTTP.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xmlHTTP.onload = function(e) {
  var arr = new Uint8Array(this.response);
  var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,arr);
  var b64 = btoa(raw);
  var dataURL="data:image/png;base64," + b64;
  console.log(b64)
};
xmlHTTP.send();
```