# Is there a way to encode CodeIgniter url?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So currently my system will send a URL like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?keyword=34` after I submit the form.

My goal is to encode the URL part at `keyword=34`. So it became like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?1safsd21` (or whatever the word that has been encoded).

I've made a little research about this problem. So far it tells me using `urlencode` or `rawurlencode` but the problem is, I don't know where to put this or how to use it.

**Form**

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/search" autocomplete="off" method="get" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" name="keyword" value="" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If security is the concern then why not `POST`?

Comment: I have to use GET method for requirements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165891/encode-base64-in-javascript-send-with-get-decode-in-php answer may help your case

Comment: use javascript to encode the query string and than submit the form using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a PHP concern, because form submissions are handled by the browser. PHP only interpretes the request and processes it. You can encode your form data with a hack like this:

```
<form id="realformdata" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/search" autocomplete="off" 
        method="get" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" 
        onsubmit="sendEncodedForm(); return false;" >
    <input type="text" name="keyword" value="" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
var sendEncodedForm = function(){
   var formdata = $("#realformdata").serialize();
   var encoded = base64_encode(formdata);
   document.location.href = $("#realformdata").attr("action") + "?" + encoded;
}
</script>
```

**Note:** `base64_encode` is just a placeholder for your encoding method. Not a real existing method.

And on the server side (PHP):

```
<?php 

$query = base64_decode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
parse_str($query);
// check $query for decoded variables
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider, you are asking about encryption. We cannot encrypt the whole `keyword=34` part, because we need a `key name` to get the parameters in controller.

However you can encrypt the value of the parameter.

You can use any of the encryption algorithms like mcrypt. Or codeigniter built in encryption library [as described here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html).

Once you done with encryption, the url will look like this. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?keyword=ENCRYPTED_TEXT`