# Nginx rewrite rule omit forward slash (/) when its first in encoded url

Tags: php, regex, nginx, pcre

I'm trying to use Nginx (`1.21.3`) rewrite, but somehow it deletes the `/` key when it's first in string.

**rewrite rule:**

```
#nginx not relevant conf here
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)data/([0-9]+)/(.+)?$ $1processor.php?key=$2&data=$3 last;
}
#nginx not relevant conf here
```

When I use this rewrite rule for any url I tested, it was okay. When I tried url like the example below, it somehow omitted the `/` in the beginning.

```
https://example.com/data/9/%2F*-%2B.%60!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()_%2B%60-%3D%5B%5D%3B%27%5C%2C.%2F%7B%7D%3A%22%7C%3C%3E%3F
```

When I reloaded `nginx` with notices and `rewrite_log=on;` I got the output:

```
2021/09/25 13:08:29 [notice] 528#528: *11710 "^(.*)data/([0-9]+)/(.+)?$" matches "/data/199/*-+.`!@#$%^&*()_+`-=[];'\,./{}:"|<>?", client: 192.168.255.107, server: localhost, request: "GET /data/199/%2F%2A-%2B.%60%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A%28%29_%2B%60-%3D%5B%5D%3B%27%5C%2C.%2F%7B%7D%3A%22%7C%3C%3E%3F HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"
```

PHP (`8.0.10`) `$_GET["data"]` output is (as you can see without `/` thus not exact math):

```
*-+.`!@#$%^&*()_+`-=[];'\,./{}:"|<>?
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: This seems like a [bug in Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37584637/8053274). I suggest you pass it as a [base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165948/8053274)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `rewrite` and `location` directives works with so-called [*normalized*](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) URI:

> The matching is performed against a normalized URI, after decoding the text encoded in the “%XX” form, resolving references to relative path components “.” and “..”, **and possible compression of two or more adjacent slashes into a single slash**.

This means that on the first stage your URL `/data/9/%2F*-%2B.%60!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()_%2B%60-%3D%5B%5D%3B%27%5C%2C.%2F%7B%7D%3A%22%7C%3C%3E%3F` gets URL-decoded:

```
/data/9//*-+.`!@#$%^&*()_+`-=[];'\,./{}:"|<>?
```

and on the second stage two adjacent slashes getting compressed into the one:

```
/data/9/*-+.`!@#$%^&*()_+`-=[];'\,./{}:"|<>?
```

Exactly the above string is subject to test for `rewrite` directive thus leading to missing of the first URL-encoded slash. However you can use the `$request_uri` variable which contains the request URI in a non-modified form. You can use either

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(?<prefix>.*/)data/(?<key>\d+)/(?<data>[^?]+)) {
    rewrite ^ ${prefix}processor.php?key=$key&data=$data;
}
```

block to be placed under **server** context or

```
location /
    if ($request_uri ~ ^(?<prefix>.*/)data/(?<key>\d+)/(?<data>[^?]+)) {
        rewrite ^ ${prefix}processor.php?key=$key&data=$data last;
    }
    ...
}
```

block placed under **location** context.

Comment: Thanks you so much Ivan, what you think about using the merge_slashes = off?

Comment: I'd rather not. It should work too, but there can be some [caveats](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes): _Note that compression is essential for the correct matching of prefix string and regular expression locations. Without it, the `//scripts/one.php` request would not match `location /scripts/ { ... }`
and might be processed as a static file. So it gets converted to `/scripts/one.php`._